# How to add dynamically paragraphs based on a certain class (javascript/jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to dynamically add certain paragraphs based on a hasClass (right / left) of a certain ID (#switch-labelX) with looping in jQuery.

What I have in initial situation (no jQuery applied yet):

```
<div class="widget-switch-btn-wrapper widget-switch-btn-wrapper-default checked">
  <small id="#switch-label1" class="widget-switch-btn right">
  </small>
</div>
<div class="widget-switch-btn-wrapper widget-switch-btn-wrapper-default checked">
  <small id="#switch-label2" class="widget-switch-btn left">
  </small>
</div>
```

Give initial labels to the switch by looping over the several "small" tags and give the switch label as the option labels as well:

```
<div class="widget-switch-btn-wrapper widget-switch-btn-wrapper-default checked">
  <small id="#switch-label1" class="widget-switch-btn right">
   <p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 1%;color: white;">Other</p>
  </small>
   <p style="text-align: left;padding-left: 15%;;color: #092a72; display:inline">Kom</p>
   <p style="text-align: left;padding-left: 35%;padding-top: 1%;color: #092a72;display:inline">Other</p>
</div>
<div class="widget-switch-btn-wrapper widget-switch-btn-wrapper-default checked">
  <small id="#switch-label2" class="widget-switch-btn left">
   <p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 1%;color: white;">Other</p>
  </small>
   <p style="text-align: left;padding-left: 15%;;color: #092a72; display:inline">Kom</p>
   <p style="text-align: left;padding-left: 35%;padding-top: 1%;color: #092a72;display:inline">Other</p>
</div>
```

Each time when the class in "small" change (right/left) it should clear/rewrite those labels (the inline paragraphs could also be written in once).

WHat I have for code now is:

```
  //find all the switch btns with the switch btn
    $(' .widget-switch-btn').each(function (index) {


            //create idlabel for switch
            var idLabel = '#switch-label' + (index + 1);

            //set the switch id for all switch btn's
            $(this).attr('id', idLabel);

//set other fixed labels
 $('.widget-switch-btn').after('<p style="text-align: left;padding-left: 15%;;color: #092a72; display:inline">Komatsu</p><p style="text-align: left;padding-left: 35%;padding-top: 1%;color: #092a72;display:inline">Other</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to watch something and react to change html,you need to add event listening.

i haven't seen button click nor event listening function, so i'm not very clear what you means. if youre still not very clear with this,please paste more complete code demos.

update:

sorry i'm still not very clear on your point of view, based on my understands of your need,i think you should add an event listener for each of your 'button' element, on an event that make your class change from 'left' to 'right' or reverse.

Then do your things in the event listening function ,like the demo code here, hope it helps you

```
$(' .widget-switch-btn').each(function (index) {
    //create idlabel for switch
    var idLabel = '#switch-label' + (index + 1);
    var classLabel = 'switch-label' + (index + 1);
        
    //set the switch id for all switch btn's
    $(this).attr('id', idLabel);
    $(this).addClass(classLabel);

    $(`#${idLabel}`).onchange = function(e) {
    // $(`#${idLabel}`).onclick = function(e) {
        if ( $(classLabel).hasClass("right")) {
           $(classLabel).html('<p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 1%;color: white;">Other</p>');
           alert("right");
         }
        //else label for "Komatsu" && paragraphs after
        else if ( $(classLabel).hasClass("left")) {
           $(classLabel).html('<p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 1%;color: white;">Kom</p>');
           alert("left");
        }
        else {}
    }
           
})
```

Comment: Hi see here the code; https://jsfiddle.net/t0rxokmq/60/

Comment: i'v updated my answer, see if it's what you need!

Answer (score 0):

First, the way you have it written you don't need the `hasClass` method. `$(idLabel+".right")` always has class 'right'. It's there in your selector.

But to make this work you need to use [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('change', idLabel, function(e) {
  $target = $(e.target); // cache the element that changed so you maintain its state
  if ($target.hasClass('right')) {
    $target.html('<p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 1%;color: white;">Other</p>');
    alert("right");
  } else if ($target.hasClass('left')) {
    $target.html('<p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 1%;color: white;">Kom</p>');
    alert("left");
  }
});
```